# Cogs - Looking in Parent Directory (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I recently reorganised my code for my discord bot, and the cogs aren't in a child directory anymore but in a parent directory. I have tried things like:

```
client.load_extension("../commands/fun.eightball")
```

and

```
client.load_extension("/home/user/bot/commands/fun.eightball")
```

but have had no success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load_extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension

that doesn't seem to take a path. "name (str) – The extension name to load. It must be dot separated like regular Python imports if accessing a sub-module. e.g. foo.test if you want to import foo/test.py."
The string seems to take the python `.` notation. Though how far it is supported and so on idk. `/` won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

client.load_extension() take paths like "folder.file", what I recommend you do to solve this is take your cogs folder into the same folder level as your bot.py so you can acess it through `client.load_extension("CogFolder.funEightball")`.

*Notice that "fun.eightball" is considered a path as parameter in client.load_extension().

What I suggest you to do as a better option is use os library to list every item in the folder where you gonna build your cogs, so you don't have to do a command line for every single cog.

```
for file in os.listdir("/home/user/bot/commands"):
    if file.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f'commands.{file[:-3]}')
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "index.py", line 35, in <module>
          client.load_extension(f'commands.{file[:-3]}')
     File "/home/user/.loacl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 649, in load_extension
          spec = importlib.util.find_spec(name)
     File"/usr/python3.7/importlib/util.py", line 94, in find_spec
          parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=["__path__"])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fun'
`
That's the error I'm getting when I try your code :/

Comment: It will not work if you do not create a folder on the same level as your "bot,py", this means that your main file must be in the same path as your cogs folder example: if your main file is in `/home/user/bot/commands` then your cogs folder should be at this path `/home/user/bot/commands/CogsFolder`, wich means you are going to use `client.load_extension(f'CogsFolder.{file[:-3]}')` and also `for file in os.listdir("/home/user/bot/commands/CogsFolder"):`